Graphql requests not served by graphql but by general spring rest
My spring boot application exposes both rest and graphql endpoints for different set of apis. Rest endpoints are working fine but graphql requests are also considered as rest and throwing 404 as it tries to serve them as static resources.
No static resource my-service/graphql
stack_trace: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource my-service/graphql.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
I've the following config in my application.properties
spring.application.name=my-service
server.port=8080
server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true
server.http2.enabled=true

management.server.port=9090
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,prometheus
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true

spring.config.import=

spring.cloud.openfeign.okhttp.enabled=true

spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true
spring.graphql.graphiql.path=/graphiql
spring.graphql.schema.printer.enabled=true
spring.graphql.path=/graphql

spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath*:graphql/**/


apollo.url=
apollo.hiveUsageClientName=my-service
apollo.hiveUsageClientVersion=1.0


Any insights on this issue are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
I've kubernets ingress configuration to route the requests to this service. Tried experimenting it changing the default servlet.context.path of the application to some prefix but didnt help

Can you add debug=true to your application.properties and show us the auto-configuration report, especially on the GraphQL-related bits?

Looking at your application.properties and your request, you are using the path my-service/graphql but you have never set your context-path to be my-service. Setting your application name does not automatically change your context path.
From the setup you have currently and supposing you are just using spring-graphql, then the path should be http://localhost:8080/graphql
If you are using MVC, then you can change the contextpath by adding the property server.servlet.context-path=my-service.
Also, just to mention it, the spring.graphql.path and spring.graphql.graphqli.path properties you have set are the defaults so you can remove those if you don't need them.
